# Problems with iptables and the access to Postgresql

Tags: centos, iptables, vps, postgresql

I am trying to configure my PostgreSQL server to have remote access, but it was impossible to make, and when I try to allow the access on Iptables result that I can't restart the iptables.

Look the configuration on pg_hba.conf

## "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only

```
local   all         all                               ident sameuser
```

## IPv4 local connections:

```
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          ident sameuser
host    all         all         184.172.135.142/24    trust
```

## IPv6 local connections:

```
host    all         all         ::1/128               ident sameuser
host    all         all         184.172.135.142/24    trust
```

The configuration on the postgresql.conf is the normal

```
listen_address='*'
```

and the line opening the port on the iptables is this:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state –state NEW -m tcp -p tcp –dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
```

and the error on the iptables is this:

```
Flushing firewall rules:                                   [  OK  ]
Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: mangle filter             [  OK  ]
Unloading iptables modules:                                [  OK  ]
'pplying iptables firewall rules: iptables-restore v1.3.5: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'mangle

Error occurred at line: 2
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

I am using a centos, vps server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have typo/error in your iptables rules config. You can check what rules you have using `iptables-save` or `iptables --line-numbers -n -L`, and fix the broken rule. Usually, they are stored in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed my issue with iptables, now the problem is on PostgreSQL:
LOG:  database system is ready
LOG:  transaction ID wrap limit is 2147484146, limited by database "postgres"
LOG:  invalid entry in file "/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf" at line 74, token "184.172.135.142/128"
FATAL:  missing or erroneous pg_hba.conf file
HINT:  See server log for details.
LOG:  invalid entry in file "/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf" at line 74, token "184.172.135.142/128"
FATAL:  missing or erroneous pg_hba.conf file
HINT:  See server log for details.